# Problems passing delegated credentials with WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, active-directory

What we are trying to do is, to have a WCF service, using WSHttpBinding, sitting on Server A that, when called, takes the credentials of what is calling it and writes a file to another server. (For the sake of this question, we will call this Server B although it could be any server that the caller has access to).

When we call this from the development PC (with both the service and caller on the same PC) or from a scheduled task on Server A this process works fine but when we call it from a client’s PC we get an “Access to the path '[destination file path]' is denied” message. This is probably the “Double Hop” issue.

Over the last few weeks (seems like months) we’ve done some research into this but nothing suggested solves the problem, it doesn’t help that there is very little recent information or any working example that use multiple PCs. 
Some of the webpages (we’ve read so many posts that we’ve lost count) we have looked at are:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/delegation-and-impersonation-with-wcf
>
> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1b65554b-f39e-4d51-be30-828d2f443067/how-to-implement-delegation-in-wcf-service?forum=wcf
>
> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b9ba685f-01c1-439b-9a18-6f9f45d04bf2/impersonated-id-is-not-being-used-in-database-access?forum=wcf
>
> http://geekswithblogs.net/manesh/archive/2009/04/23/setting-up-wcf-to-impersonate-client-credentials.aspx
>
> [Configuring a WCF service (Web.config) - HttpsGetEnabled, HttpsGetUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127624/configuring-a-wcf-service-web-config-httpsgetenabled-httpsgeturl)
>
> https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38979/How-to-enable-multi-hop-impersonation-using-constr
>
> [WCF and passing windows credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356721/wcf-and-passing-windows-credentials)

Part of the problem is that we are not sure where the problem resides (in code, web config, on the server, IIS site, IIS Application Pool, the AD or a combination of these)

As part a test process (code below) that writes a log, some things what we’ve spotted that don’t make sense:

- When checking the ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.ImpersonationLevel it
  is returning “Impersonation” – if our understanding is correct this
  should be delegation.
- When checking the ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.AuthenticationType  it
  is returning  “NTLM” despite the web config turning this off
- A number of web posts mention that we should be disabling "**Anonymous Authentication**” but every time we do this we get the following error

  > The authentication schemes configured on the host ('IntegratedWindowsAuthentication') do not allow those configured on the binding 'WSHttpBinding' ('Anonymous').  Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to Transport or TransportCredentialOnly.  Additionally, this may be resolved by changing the authentication schemes for this application through the IIS management tool, through the ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the application configuration file at the 
  >   element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding,
  >   or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the
  >   HttpTransportBindingElement.

However, when we try to enable Transport security mode we get

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the
>   endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes
>   are [http].

Calling Code (on PC)

```
public StringBuilder Messages { get; private set; }

private void cmdReadFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
            Messages.AppendLine("Attempting to read folder location " + txtRemoteLoc.Text + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

            try
            {
                DelegationService.ControllerClient tester = new DelegationService.ControllerClient();
                tester.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;

                List<string> fileListings = new List<string>();
                fileListings = tester.ReadFolder(txtRemoteLoc.Text);
                Messages.AppendLine("Transfer returns a list of " + fileListings.Count() + " files");
                foreach (string file in fileListings)
                {
                    lsvFiles.Items.Add(file);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Messages.AppendLine("An error has occured in cmdReadFolder_Click");
                Messages.AppendLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Messages.AppendLine("cmdReadFolder_Click ends " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(Messages.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Interface

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace DelegationTest
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITransfer
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<string> ReadLocation(string location);

        [OperationContract]
        string Upload(byte[] file, string filename, string toLocation);            
    }        
}
```

a "doing" function

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
    public List<string> ReadLocation(string location)
    {
        List<string> matchedFiles = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            using (ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
            {
                matchedFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(location).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = "****Error Windows ReadLocation - Error message: " + ex.Message;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                msg += "\nInner error Message: " + ex.InnerException.Message;
            throw (ex);
        }
        return matchedFiles;
    }
```

Web Config (some attempts have been commented out and left in to what we've tried)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="DelegationTest.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
     <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />    
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ControlerBind" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="16" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="8192" />
          <reliableSession enabled="true" />
       <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
    <!--   <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" /> 
    </security>        -->
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="DelegationTest.Controller">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ControlerBind" contract="DelegationTest.IController">          
        </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MexControlerBind" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://[ServerA]/DelegationTest/DelegationTest.Controller.svc" />
           <add baseAddress="https://[ServerA]/DelegationTest/DelegationTest.Controller.svc" /> 
          </baseAddresses>
        </host> 
      </service>
      <service name="DelegationTest.Transfer">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ControlerBind" contract="DelegationTest.ITransfer">
          <identity>
            <!-- <dns value="localhost" /> -->
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MexControlerBind" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://[ServerA]/DelegationTest/DelegationTest.Transfer.svc" />
           <add baseAddress="https://[ServerA]/DelegationTest/DelegationTest.Transfer.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behaviiorTest">
          <clientCredentials>
            <windows allowNtlm="false" allowedImpersonationLevel="Delegation" />
            <httpDigest impersonationLevel="Delegation" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
          <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
          <!-- <serviceAuthenticationManager authenticationSchemes="IntegratedWindowsAuthentication"/> -->
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>  
</configuration>
```

Sorry for the long question

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: you could try to set the site application pool identity as a domain user. please refer this link for more detail:[link1](https://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/232967), [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-impersonation-with-transport-security), [link3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/debugging-windows-authentication-errors)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I've tried changing the application pool identity to all of the built in users & a "real" network user, but no change. I am investigating the links you've included